# TYPO3: How do I insert page content from parent page into subpages

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to insert to all sub pages content element from parent page using TypoScript? I don't want to use the `insert record` CE. On Parent page I only have image in left column - nothing else. I would like to "copy" that image to left column on all sub pages of that parent page.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you want to use [`Content Slide`](http://wiki.typo3.org/Content_Slide)

For the same within TemplaVoilà take a look at [`KB TV Content Slide`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kb_tv_cont_slide) ext

Comment: I think it will be good - today I will try it, but the name of ext... it should be "column content replicator" or something like that

Comment: Content slide is official feature name from TSref ;) so additional ext is *-slide too :)

Comment: I found the problem with "sliding" CE from my own extension. On parent page everything is ok but on sub page I see only title without content.

Comment: What is te extension? pi, or extbase?

Comment: pi (unfortunately). I cleaned the ext to primary version and now I can see mode selector and search bar but without content (list element)

Comment: Sorry, no idea, you know I'm not PI fan

Comment: I found the reason - my ext can't find the reference to list element on subpages. The solution - general storage page :) Now it works perfectly.